# iOS 8 Action Extension for selected text in Safari

Tags: ios8, mobile-safari, action, ios8-extension

I can't get Action Extensions to work with selected text in safari.
Inside Activation rules there is the rule to allow text, but the extension is not available when I select the text.

Comment: Please add some code indicating what you've tried and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount to make extension available in Safari.

When you create a non-UI action extension target from the template, an Action.js file is automatically created. Edit the file to send back the selected text using

```
document.getSelection().toString()
```

Comment: Did you try out this code? I've done exactly as described but document.getSelection().toString() always returns an empty string. (Returning other data from the javascript works as expected.)

Comment: Yup, this works for me. I have an app out that uses it.

Comment: Would you be so kind to post some code? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @honcheng `I have an app out that uses it.` I would love to check your app out. Can you please post the link?